# How can multiple webapps in the same tomcat instance share database connection pool?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, saas, multi-tenant

Having in mind that each webapp has its own separate database (but all databases are in the same database server).

The scenario is that I have a multi-tenant saas application - I deploy the same application for each customer. Each customer works on a database that is called `db_cid`, where `cid` is the customer id, i.e. a a unique customer identifier.

Working with hibernate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to share ressources between web application you must let the web container manage them, and  put them in JNDI.    The web application can then get the resources from a JNDI context very easily.

JDBC connection pools are so typical so every web container documents how to set them up.

For stand-alone programs we use Simple JNDI http://www.osjava.org/simple-jndi/ which provides the external configuration which allows us to separate codebase from configuration completely.

Try it, you'll like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about configuring a JNDI connection in the tomcat (global) context? It can be a pooled connection, as described in [JNDI datasource example](http://www.mbaworld.com/docs/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).